# How do I configure my soundcard for 5.1 sound?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am very new to Ubuntu and linux as I have used windows only until yesterday.

I am attempting to send my audio signal to my pioneer receiver using a single digital optical cable which is plugged into my M2N SLI Deluxe motherboard.

I am sending video with a Geforce 8600GT video card through HDMI. That card does not support audio through HDMI.

The only thing I have got to work so far is my left channel speaker acts as a stereo left and my sub woofer is trying to act as a stereo right.

I was able to achieve this through altering the alsamixer settings. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 channel sound when 5.1 is expected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91506/2-channel-sound-when-5-1-is-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pavucontrol` is a great tool to control where your audio should go.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Control by application:
[image]

Control by output device:
[image]

Comment: I think this will work. It was a combination of getting to know my reciever better and this program helping me have more precise control over the outputs. Thanks