# Only two audio channels work on an Acer 4830T

Tags: sound, acer, alsa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 channel sound when 5.1 is expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91506/2-channel-sound-when-5-1-is-expected)

I have been trying to get the Surround sound working on my laptop for a couple of hours now. I have the Acter TimelineX 4830T, and I have gotten everything working accept the speakers. It has a 5.1 surround system built in, but only the front left and right speaker work.

Any help would be appreciated.

And here is the ALSA Information: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=448f38630385f020faf6dc204b551f8398c53e96

Comment: Have you tried with a 5.1 channel **source**? Eg movie DVD?

Comment: Takkat, I just tried that. It enabled the 5.1 for HDMI, but it does not work for the onboard speakers. Sound only comes out if I have Analog Stereo Output selected as the profile

Answer (score 0):

I also have a timeline 4830t.  It only has 2 internal speaker, so it is not possible to get Dolby 5.1 sound.  The advertised 5.1 Dolby is for HDMI output.  Have you tried connecting it to your home theater?  I have test internal speaker in Windows 7, and Ubuntu 12.04 and the preform the same.