# Rear speakers and subwoofers not working in Ubuntu 12.04 on HP dv6

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp, speakers

I have an HP DV6-6154tx laptop and i recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 with dual boot on it.

The Problem is only two of my speakers are working and the sub-woofers also are not working.

The result is extremely quiet sound from my laptop.

Please help.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91506/2-channel-sound-when-5-1-is-expected

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop, I found a partial solution. With this solution the sub-woofers don't mute on headphone plug in.

open the file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add the line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=ref
```

If you find a better solution please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Open

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

add the line:

options snd-hda-intel model=ref

Instead of 'ref';

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.19/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt

Is a list of models- instead of model=ref put in your model- or the most similar, eg, im running a hpdm4, I use model=hp-dv7-4000

I then use alsamixer from terminal to alter the volumes of the speakers, discovering as i do that bass is coming out the front speakers, and other channels through the subwoofer.

There is a method to swap these, but you will have to google it!(am in a  hurry)

Paul